# Terraform with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want an engineer to only use Terraform to provision the infrastructure in AWS and to verify if provisioning was successful he/she should have read-only access in the AWS console. So that the engineer should not make changes to resources at the console inadvertently.

What are the possible ways to achieve this?

Comment: So changes using AWS CLI, SDK or TF are fine? Why only console should be read only? If so then just don't give console access.

Comment: yes only TF, is it possible to block CLI and SDK too? What all implications it should cause to TF provisioning? I guess we need to have programmatic access to perform provisioning but not sure if TF and CLI or SDK operations are inter-related.

Comment: If you block SLI and SDK you will block TF as well.Create a sandbox/dev account for testing the infrastructure, and then only you are going to deploy the changes to main account.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. Will try that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your users read-only access to the console - and use IAM policies to allow only specific EC2 instances appropriate access to provision infrastructure, and enforce all of your terraform to be executed from those EC2 instances.